# PID tuning for Quadcopter

Tags: quadcopter, pid

I have been stabilizing my quadcopter. I tuned my angle PIDies and my quadcopter tries to stabilize itself, but there is some overshooting. Which is, I think, due to gyro rates. I have read that we have to use two PIDies on an axis. I'm having problems to attach these two PIDies.

Can anyone help me in cascading angle PID and rate PID? Will I have to tune rate PID after tuning angle PID?

Comment: This might be of help: http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/pid-output-does-not-reach-setpoint-precisely-enough